# Rellenar los campo nombre, apellidos y mail de un formulario web basado en una lista de excel

Tags: excel, vba

tengo un excel con 3 columnas (nombre, apellido y mail) son gente que se quiere apuntar a un seminario web de la plataforma Gotowebinar. He creado un macro en excel que teóricamente debería rellenar los campos en base al excel, hacer click sobre el boton registrar y luego hacer lo mismo con la siguiente fila. El error que me da es el siguiente:

Se ha producido el error '424' en tiempo de ejecución:
Se requiere un objeto

El cógido que utilizo es el siguiente:

Sub inscripciones()

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/8357104619320871183"

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set doc = IE.document

For intRow = 2 To 4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'doc.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = "pato"
'doc.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = "pequin"
'doc.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = "patopequin@super.com"
'doc.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'doc.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2").Value
'doc.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B2").Value
'doc.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").Value
'doc.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IE.document.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & intRow).Value
IE.document.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B" & intRow).Value
IE.document.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C" & intRow).Value
IE.document.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

Next

IE.Quit
```

End Sub

Comment: Los controles a los que llamas tienen eventos JS asociados. Probablemente debas ejecutar esos eventos antes de enviar la información.

Answer (score 0):

Paso a paso no salta ningún error. El problema viene cuando intentas ejecutarlo de golpe... En determinadas ocasiones la web no ha cargado completamente y por eso tira ese error. En otras ocasiones he visto que el error lo tira cuando completa un registro duplicado y no consigue volver a la página de registro.

Cada página es un mundo y no todas se comportan igual... de ahí que aunque intentes controlar si se ha cargado o no la web con IE.Busy o IE.readyState en ocasiones falla.

He probado esperando 5 segundos tras la carga de la web y, tras cada click, vuelvo a cargar la página de registro con:

```
IE.navigate "https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/8357104619320871183"
```

El código quedaría así:

```
Sub inscripciones()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/8357104619320871183"
    
'    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
'    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
'    Loop
    
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 5, Now)
    
    Set doc = IE.document
    
    For intRow = 1 To 2
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = "pato"
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = "pequin"
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = "patopequin@super.com"
    'doc.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A2").Value
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B2").Value
    'doc.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C2").Value
    'doc.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click
    '------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IE.document.getElementById("registrant.firstName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    IE.document.getElementById("registrant.lastName").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("B" & intRow).Value
    IE.document.getElementById("registrant.email").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Range("C" & intRow).Value
    IE.document.getElementById("registration.submit.button").Click
    IE.navigate "https://register.gotowebinar.com/register/8357104619320871183"
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    
    Next
    
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Lo he probado varias veces y no da error. Eso sí, supongo que si la velocidad de conexión es lenta y la web no carga completamente en esos 5 segundos probablemente siga dando error.

Comment: Muchas gracias Dogwall, he conseguido rellenar los campos del formulario de registro web sin error pero al dar al botón de registrar no reconoce los datos que he introducido via macro y me pide que los rellene. Debajo de cada campo pone: "Indique su nombre" o "Indique su apellido". Es decir en el campo nombre yo veo en la pantalla Luis pero el formulario no lo reconoce y en el momento en que modifico el campo con una letra o un espacio lo reconoce y me desaparece la peticion de "Indique su nombre". Puedes ser que tenga algún tipo de protección antispam? Como puedo solucionarlo?